# Oracle EBS REST API

Tags: sql, oracle, rest, api

I am not able to figure out how to use the EBS Rest APIs. I need to process Sales Orders on my EBS Rest API. I am using the OE_ORDER_PUB interface. The rest calls that I am using include the Process_Header, Process_Lines and Get_Order. I deployed the APIs and that is working, but I am not why my requests are returning null. I don't know which Base Table that these APIs are saving/retrieving from.

Here is my request body for creating Process Header.

```
    {
    "InputParameters":{
        "P_HEADER_REC" : "G_MISS_HEADER_REC",
        "P_ORG_ID":2131,
        "P_OPERATING_UNIT":"test"
    }
}
```

Here is part of the Response:

```
    {
    "OutputParameters": {
        "@xmlns": "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/ont/rest/order/process_header/",
        "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "X_HEADER_OUT_REC": {
            "ACCOUNTING_RULE_ID": null,
            "PARTY_TYPE": null,
            "AGREEMENT_ID": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE1": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE10": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE11": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE12": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE13": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE14": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE15": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE16": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE17": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE18": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE19": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE2": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE20": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE3": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE4": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE5": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE6": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE7": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE8": null,
            "ATTRIBUTE9": null,
            "BOOKED_FLAG": null,
            "CANCELLED_FLAG": null,
            "CONTEXT": null,
            "CONVERSION_RATE": null,
            "CONVERSION_RATE_DATE": null,
            "CONVERSION_TYPE_CODE": null,
            "CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE_SET_CODE": null,
            "CREATED_BY": null,
            "CREATION_DATE": null,
            "CUST_PO_NUMBER": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_ORG_ID": null,
            "DEMAND_CLASS_CODE": null,
            "EARLIEST_SCHEDULE_LIMIT": null,
            "EXPIRATION_DATE": null,
            "FOB_POINT_CODE": null,
            "FREIGHT_CARRIER_CODE": null,
            "FREIGHT_TERMS_CODE": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE1": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE10": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE11": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE12": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE13": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE14": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE15": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE16": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE17": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE18": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE19": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE2": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE20": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE3": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE4": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE5": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE6": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE7": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE8": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE9": null,
            "GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY": null,
            "TP_CONTEXT": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE1": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE2": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE3": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE4": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE5": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE6": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE7": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE8": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE9": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE10": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE11": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE12": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE13": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE14": null,
            "TP_ATTRIBUTE15": null,
            "HEADER_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_ORG_ID": null,
            "INVOICING_RULE_ID": null,
            "LAST_UPDATED_BY": null,
            "LAST_UPDATE_DATE": null,
            "LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN": null,
            "LATEST_SCHEDULE_LIMIT": null,
            "OPEN_FLAG": null,
            "ORDER_CATEGORY_CODE": null,
            "ORDERED_DATE": null,
            "ORDER_DATE_TYPE_CODE": null,
            "ORDER_NUMBER": null,
            "ORDER_SOURCE_ID": null,
            "ORDER_TYPE_ID": null,
            "ORG_ID": null,
            "ORIG_SYS_DOCUMENT_REF": null,
            "PARTIAL_SHIPMENTS_ALLOWED": null,
            "PAYMENT_TERM_ID": null,
            "PRICE_LIST_ID": null,
            "PRICE_REQUEST_CODE": null,
            "PRICING_DATE": null,
            "PROGRAM_APPLICATION_ID": null,
            "PROGRAM_ID": null,
            "PROGRAM_UPDATE_DATE": null,
            "REQUEST_DATE": null,
            "REQUEST_ID": null,
            "RETURN_REASON_CODE": null,
            "SALESREP_ID": null,
            "SALES_CHANNEL_CODE": null,
            "SHIPMENT_PRIORITY_CODE": null,
            "SHIPPING_METHOD_CODE": null,
            "SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TOLERANCE_ABOVE": null,
            "SHIP_TOLERANCE_BELOW": null,
            "SHIP_TO_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_ORG_ID": null,
            "SOLD_FROM_ORG_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_ORG_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_PHONE_ID": null,
            "SOURCE_DOCUMENT_ID": null,
            "SOURCE_DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID": null,
            "TAX_EXEMPT_FLAG": null,
            "TAX_EXEMPT_NUMBER": null,
            "TAX_EXEMPT_REASON_CODE": null,
            "TAX_POINT_CODE": null,
            "TRANSACTIONAL_CURR_CODE": null,
            "VERSION_NUMBER": null,
            "RETURN_STATUS": null,
            "DB_FLAG": null,
            "OPERATION": null,
            "FIRST_ACK_CODE": null,
            "FIRST_ACK_DATE": null,
            "LAST_ACK_CODE": null,
            "LAST_ACK_DATE": null,
            "CHANGE_REASON": null,
            "CHANGE_COMMENTS": null,
            "CHANGE_SEQUENCE": null,
            "CHANGE_REQUEST_CODE": null,
            "READY_FLAG": null,
            "STATUS_FLAG": null,
            "FORCE_APPLY_FLAG": null,
            "DROP_SHIP_FLAG": null,
            "CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_TERM_ID": null,
            "PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE": null,
            "PAYMENT_AMOUNT": null,
            "CHECK_NUMBER": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_CODE": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_HOLDER_NAME": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_APPROVAL_CODE": null,
            "CREDIT_CARD_APPROVAL_DATE": null,
            "SHIPPING_INSTRUCTIONS": null,
            "PACKING_INSTRUCTIONS": null,
            "FLOW_STATUS_CODE": null,
            "BOOKED_DATE": null,
            "MARKETING_SOURCE_CODE_ID": null,
            "UPGRADED_FLAG": null,
            "LOCK_CONTROL": null,
            "SHIP_TO_EDI_LOCATION_CODE": null,
            "SOLD_TO_EDI_LOCATION_CODE": null,
            "BILL_TO_EDI_LOCATION_CODE": null,
            "SHIP_FROM_EDI_LOCATION_CODE": null,
            "SHIP_FROM_ADDRESS_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_ADDRESS_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_ADDRESS_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_CODE": null,
            "XML_MESSAGE_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_CUSTOMER_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_CUSTOMER_ID": null,
            "ACCOUNTING_RULE_DURATION": null,
            "XML_TRANSACTION_TYPE_CODE": null,
            "BLANKET_NUMBER": null,
            "LINE_SET_NAME": null,
            "FULFILLMENT_SET_NAME": null,
            "DEFAULT_FULFILLMENT_SET": null,
            "QUOTE_DATE": null,
            "QUOTE_NUMBER": null,
            "SALES_DOCUMENT_NAME": null,
            "TRANSACTION_PHASE_CODE": null,
            "USER_STATUS_CODE": null,
            "DRAFT_SUBMITTED_FLAG": null,
            "SOURCE_DOCUMENT_VERSION_NUMBER": null,
            "SOLD_TO_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "MINISITE_ID": null,
            "IB_OWNER": null,
            "IB_INSTALLED_AT_LOCATION": null,
            "IB_CURRENT_LOCATION": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "SUPPLIER_SIGNATURE": null,
            "SUPPLIER_SIGNATURE_DATE": null,
            "CUSTOMER_SIGNATURE": null,
            "CUSTOMER_SIGNATURE_DATE": null,
            "SOLD_TO_PARTY_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_ORG_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_PARTY_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_PARTY_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_PARTY_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_PARTY_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_PARTY_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_PARTY_SITE_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_PARTY_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_PARTY_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_PARTY_SITE_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_PARTY_SITE_USE_ID": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_PARTY_NUMBER": null,
            "END_CUSTOMER_ORG_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_PARTY_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_CUSTOMER_PARTY_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_CUSTOMER_PARTY_ID": null,
            "SHIP_TO_ORG_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_ORG_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_ORG_CONTACT_ID": null,
            "CONTRACT_TEMPLATE_ID": null,
            "CONTRACT_SOURCE_DOC_TYPE_CODE": null,
            "CONTRACT_SOURCE_DOCUMENT_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_PARTY_NUMBER": null,
            "SHIP_TO_PARTY_NUMBER": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_PARTY_NUMBER": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_PARTY_NUMBER": null,
            "ORDER_FIRMED_DATE": null,
            "INSTRUMENT_SECURITY_CODE": null,
            "CC_INSTRUMENT_ID": null,
            "CC_INSTRUMENT_ASSIGNMENT_ID": null,
            "SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_REF": null,
            "SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_REF": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_CUSTOMER_REF": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_CUSTOMER_REF": null,
            "SHIP_TO_ADDRESS_REF": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_ADDRESS_REF": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_ADDRESS_REF": null,
            "SOLD_TO_ADDRESS_REF": null,
            "SOLD_TO_CONTACT_REF": null,
            "SHIP_TO_CONTACT_REF": null,
            "INVOICE_TO_CONTACT_REF": null,
            "DELIVER_TO_CONTACT_REF": null
        },
        "X_RETURN_STATUS": "E",
        "X_MSG_COUNT": "8",
        "X_MSG_DATA": "ONT OE_BOTH_VAL_AND_ID_EXIST N ATTRIBUTE operating_unit "
    }
}
```

I do not know how to create a proper payload. I know that is those are the correct parameter names, but I am not sure what else there is.

Comment: Well, first, you can't pass a record in as a string, you have to break it down into elements such as you see in the response. Have you tried calling the APIs in a PL/SQL anonymous block? Did it work for the params you passed? Can you post the code for the anon block, if so?

Comment: I havent tried PL/SQL anonymous block, because I am focused on trying to get it working solely using REST API. I am not familiar with EBS Orders. 
I never got it working, because I do not know the parameters needed to pass in the REST API. 
Yeah I know that "P_HEADER_REC" would not work with a simple string, but I do not know the keys for this collection.

Comment: I suggest starting with the anonymous block because you don't yet know whether your parameters are incorrect, or the structure of your JSON is incorrect. Once you are sure of your parameters in the anon block, you can work on structuring the JSON. Make sense?

Comment: @Acroyear I guess that is start and I will do that next. Ideally, I would like parameters. Thanks